# How to query data between two specific months for all years?

Tags: oracle

Need to query the data between two months of all years.

For Example:

Table 1 --> contains 100 records for 10 years

Column --> Created date

Need to pull the data between April to May for all years

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) function.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TABLE1(ID INT, CREATED_DATE DATE);
> INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1, TO_DATE('20180101', 'YYYYMMDD'));
> INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1, TO_DATE('20180201', 'YYYYMMDD'));
> INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1, TO_DATE('20180301', 'YYYYMMDD'));
> INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1, TO_DATE('20180401', 'YYYYMMDD'));
> INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1, TO_DATE('20170401', 'YYYYMMDD'));
> INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1, TO_DATE('20180501', 'YYYYMMDD'));
> INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1, TO_DATE('20180601', 'YYYYMMDD'));
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM   TABLE1
> WHERE  EXTRACT (MONTH FROM CREATED_DATE) >= 4
> AND    EXTRACT (MONTH FROM CREATED_DATE) <= 5;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | CREATED_DATE
> -: | :-----------
>  1 | 01-APR-18   
>  1 | 01-APR-17   
>  1 | 01-MAY-18
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2eedd4bce1e4d48ed36a284fe9ffbb86)*

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
from T
where extract(month from date_column) between :start_month_number and :end_month_number;
```

This won't work across YEAR boundaries.